# Calling a generator of saga is going to a infinite loop

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

From my Component that is Expense Creator want to delete a component which is being generated from array of object via map method in Expense Statement, which is connected to Redux and saga.(Where detail being stored in Store and local Storage as well).

Issue Here is with Saga, Where delete Function renders again again which stuck to an Infinite loop.

Here is the Basic Flow Related to Delete Function,

/1)Expense Statement Component in Component Folder

> ```
> class ExpenseStatment extends Component {
>    
>     render() {
>         let expenses = this.props.expense.map(expense => {
>         return(<ExpenseCreator 
>                 key={expense.id}
>                 id={expense.id}
>                 title = {expense.title}
>                 price = {expense.price}
>                 editHandler = {this.props.onEdit}
>                 deleteHandler = {this.props.onDelete}
>             /> )
>         })
>         return (
>             <div className="ExpenseStatment">
>                 {expenses}
>             </div>
>         )
>     }
> }
>
> const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
>     return{
>         onEdit : (id) => dispatch (budgetAction.editHandler(id)),
>         onDelete : (id) => dispatch (budgetAction.deleteHandler(id))
>     }
> }
> ```

/2)Expense Creator Component in Expense Statment

> ```
> export default class ExpenseCreator extends Component {
>     render() {
>         return (
>             <div className = "ExpenseCreator" >
>                 <p>{this.props.title}</p>
>                 <p>{this.props.price}</p>
>                 <Button onClick={()=>this.props.editHandler(this.props.id)}><EditIcon/></Button>
>                 <Button onClick={()=>this.props.deleteHandler(this.props.id)}><DeleteIcon/></Button>
>             </div>
>         )
>     }
> }
> ```

/3)Reducer File
/Action Creator

> ```
> export const deleteHandler = (id) =>{>         
>     return{
>         type : DELETE_INIT,
>         id :id
>     }
> }
> ```

> ```
> export const deleteHandlerSuccess = (budgetApp) =>{
>     return{
>         type : DELETE_INIT,
>         expense : budgetApp.expense,
>   expenditure : budgetApp.expenditure
>     }
> }
> ```

/4) Saga

> ```
> export function* deleteHandlerSaga(action){
>     const localValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("budgetApp"));
>     const updateValue = {...localValue};
>     const editObjIndex = updateValue.expense.findIndex(item => item.id === action.id)
>     updateValue.expense.splice(editObjIndex,1);
>     const fetchPrice = updateValue.expense.map(x=>x.price).reduce((a,c) => a+c);
>     updateValue.expenditure = fetchPrice;
>     updateValue.editMode = false;
>     console.log(updateValue.expense);
>     yield localStorage.setItem("budgetApp",JSON.stringify(updateValue));
>     yield put (actionType.deleteHandlerSuccess(updateValue);
> }
> ```

/5) Reducer

> ```
> case DELETE_SUCCESS:
>             return{
>                 ...state,
>                 expense:action.expense,
>       expenditure : action.expenditure
>             }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in your action creators.  `deleteHandlerSuccess` has type `DELETE_INIT` but it should be `DELETE_SUCCESS`.

This causes an infinite loop because completing the delete causes it to start again instead of saving the results.